# How to convert an Interval to a LocalDate range in NodaTime?

Tags: c#, .net, nodatime

> I'm running into a scenario where I need to convert an `Interval` value to Enumerable collection of `LocalDate` in NodaTime. How can I do that?

Below is the code

```
Interval invl = obj.Interval; 
//Here is the Interval value i.e.,{2016-10-20T00:00:00Z/2016-11-03T00:00:00Z}
```

How can I form a Date range between these intervals?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A slightly alternative approach to the one given by Niyoko:

- Convert both `Instant` values into `LocalDate`
- Implement a range between them

I'm assuming that the interval is exclusive - so if the end point represents *exactly* midnight in the target time zone, you exclude that day, otherwise you include it.

So the method below includes every date which is covered within the interval, in the given time zone.

```
public IEnumerable<LocalDate> DatesInInterval(Interval interval, DateTimeZone zone)
{
    LocalDate start = interval.Start.InZone(zone).Date;
    ZonedDateTime endZonedDateTime = interval.End.InZone(zone);
    LocalDate end = endLocalDateTime.Date;
    if (endLocalDateTime.TimeOfDay == LocalTime.Midnight)
    {
        end = end.PlusDays(-1);
    }
    for (LocalDate date = start; date <= end; date = date.PlusDays(1))
    {
        yield return date;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll try it out with your solution. Also, I'm getting an error like `Cannot implicitly convert type 'NodaTime.ZonedDateTime' to 'NodaTime.LocalDateTime'`. Converting `LocalDateTime` to `ZonedDateTime` solved the error. Am I right in doing that?

Comment: Thanks @Jon Skeet.

Answer (score 2):

Use this code:

```
var l = Enumerable.Range(0, int.MaxValue)
            .Select(x => Period.FromDays(x))
            .Select(x => LocalDate.Add(interval.Start.InZone(localZone).Date, x))
            .TakeWhile(x => x.CompareTo(interval.End.InZone(localZone).Date) <= 0);
```

Example:

```
var localZone = DateTimeZone.ForOffset(Offset.FromHours(7));

var start = Instant.FromDateTimeOffset(new DateTimeOffset(new DateTime(2016, 10, 1)));
var end = Instant.FromDateTimeOffset(new DateTimeOffset(new DateTime(2016, 10, 25)));

var interval = new Interval(start, end);

var l = Enumerable.Range(0, int.MaxValue)
        .Select(x => Period.FromDays(x))
        .Select(x => LocalDate.Add(interval.Start.InZone(localZone).Date, x))
        .TakeWhile(x => x.CompareTo(interval.End.InZone(localZone).Date) <= 0);

foreach (var localDate in l)
{
    Console.WriteLine(localDate);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Your solution works fine. But could you explain about the DateTimeZone object `localZone`?, as it sets an Offset value.

Comment: @Karthik It is used to convert `Instant` to `LocalDate` because `Instant` is timezone-agnostic. Change it according to your local timezone.

Comment: Or you can automatically get local timezone by calling `DateTimeZoneProviders.Bcl.GetSystemDefault()`

Comment: Thanks @Niyoko Yuliawan.